# Express Morgan not writing logs to file or STDOUT

Tags: node.js, express, logging

I have an Express application that I would like to add logging to. I installed Morgan and set up the middleware in the file which manages my API calls:

*/src/api/calls.js*

the morgan middleware is set up to send the logging results to a file: errors.txt

```
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        dbConfig = require('../config/db.config'),
        connectToMongo = require('./db.js'),
        bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
        ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
        morgan = require('morgan'),
        fs = require('fs'),
        Sb;

    //middleware
    var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream('../sample/errors.txt', {flags: 'a'})
    app.use(morgan('combined',  {stream: accessLogStream}));

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

module.exports = function apiRoutes(app) {
  app.get("/v1/api/sample/:call", function(req, res, next) {
     //route db calls and code here
  });
}
```

*/app.js*

the api routes are required into the app.js file and the apiRoutes function is called:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./src/config/server.config');
//api and server
var http = require('http');
var server = new http.Server(app);

//load the api calls for the server
var apiRoutes = require('./src/api/calls.js');
apiRoutes(app);
```

the problem is - I'm not getting any logging data written into my errors.txt file or even in the console when I change the code to simply STDOUT. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out- the logging code needed to be located in the app.js file, not in the file that holds the api calls. I knew the logging code needed to be the first piece of middleware, but I didn't realize it needed to be right after the new instance of the server is instantiated.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    config = require('./src/config/server.config'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    fs = require('fs'),
//api and server
    http = require('http'),
    server = new http.Server(app); 

//set up the logger
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'})
app.use(morgan('combined',  {"stream": accessLogStream}));


//load the api calls for the server
var apiRoutes = require('./src/api/calls.js');
apiRoutes(app);
```

Comment: That is absolutely correct. I got the same issue and your solution saves my day. Thanks!

Comment: What if you had `app.use(morgan('combined',  {"stream": accessLogStream}));` _before_ `new http.Server(app); `?

Answer (score 10):

In case you are running/debugging your Node code from *VS Code*, then this problem is caused by *VS Code*.

*Morgan* writes to console via `process.stdout.write`, which is not supported by VS Code's *Debug Console*. The *Debug Console* will show only things written via `console.log`.

There are two ways to fix this. Both include adding entires to `launch.json`:

- first solution - add `"console": "integratedTerminal"`
- second solution - add `"outputCapture": "std"` (will not respect log colors)

I found this solutions here:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19750
- [Where is stdout for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810557/where-is-stdout-for-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

when using express, it works for me

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I moved the following code to the start of the `app.js` file, then it started working:

```
app.use(logger('combined'));
app.use(logger('common', {
    stream: fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'})
}));
```

For some reason, when this was at the beginning of the file:

```
app.use(logger('combined'));
```

And this was at the end:

```
app.use(logger('common', {
    stream: fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'})
}));
```

Then it didn't work. I didn't figure out why.

Comment: The solution worked for me, Thanks!! But I didn't understand the reason behind it