# Where is stdout for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running Node.js in VS Code. I see output of `console.log` in the Debug Window.

Where does `process.stdout.write` go to? I can't find it in the Debug Console or any of the Output windows.

My launch.json is simply this:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/job.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your debug config section?

Comment: I have added `launch.json`. Not sure if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 30):

Looking at [issues with process.stdout.write](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19750) the suggested fixes are adding these to your launch config:

```
"console": "internalConsole", 
"outputCapture": "std",
```

Especially the **outputCapture** entry is important.

Comment: 4me just "outputCapture":"std" was sufficient

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the **Debug Console** is visible:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to add `"console": "internalConsole"` to your config and see if it works?

[As per the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) these are the available options for the `console`:

> console - what kind of console to use, for example, **internalConsole**,
>   **integratedTerminal**, **externalTerminal**