# How to debug Deno in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, deno

How do we configure `.vscode/launch.json` to debug Deno projects?

The IntelliSense the VSCode provides when I was in `configurations` didn't offer an option for Deno. Or is there an extension for this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to attach the debugger, as per [the deno manual](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/debugging_your_code#vscode).

Create `.vscode/launch.json` replacing `<entry_point>` with your actual script and then <kbd>F5</kbd>.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Deno",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "-A", "<entry_point>"],
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

It will stop at the breakpoints you set on VS Code, tried here and it worked fine.

About the VS Code plugin:

> Official support in plugin is being worked on -
> https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/12

Comment: Upvoted. I also had to add `"outputCapture": "std"` to see logs in the debug console.

Comment: after spending hours on github and google, this worked in a second. Note: had to add `"outputCapture": "std"` for console logs. thanks @ford04

Comment: The link to the deno manual seems to be dead.

Comment: @TrentVB it did in fact changed. I updated in the answer, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The debugging will not work with this configuration. You also need to set `"debug.javascript.usePreview": false` in your settings because https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/12#issuecomment-656406826

Comment: And now that the preview has become the default, that setting is useless again, and Deno breakpoints don't work yet again. No idea how to fix it.

Comment: All this worked for me, but I needed to change `"port"` to `"attachSimplePort"` [as described elsewhere](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/12#issuecomment-658957984).

Comment: why is it `"type": "node"` but not `"type": "deno"`? Is it that I have to install node before deno to run the debug?

Answer (score 13):

The official [VS Code Deno extension](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno) comes with handy [debug support](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/pull/221) starting with [v2.3.0](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/releases/tag/v2.3.0).

Screencast from the PR:

[image]

### Fresh projects

You can already press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug the active file without `launch.json` (quite useful).

To auto-generate `launch.json` with a `Deno` entry: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Open debug view) → "create a launch.json file" → Deno

### Add Deno entry in existing `launch.json`

Press `Add Configuration...` in opened `launch.json` (see screencast above).
<kbd>F5</kbd> will now trigger the currently active debug launch action.

### Launch active file

To debug the currently active file in case of an already configured `launch.json`, change:

```
{
  "type": "pwa-node",
  "program": "${file}", // change "program" value to "${file}"
  // ...
},
```

### Create debug selection shortcut

```
// Inside keybindings.json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "workbench.action.debug.selectandstart",
    "args": "Start debug task"
},
```

The shortcut is called `"Debug: Select and Start Debugging"` - see also [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645098/vscode-keyboard-shortcut-for-launch-configuration).

### Enable log output in Debug Console

To have log output shown in the debug console, I still needed to add `"outputCapture": "std"` to the config entry. More infos:

- [Where is stdout for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810557/where-is-stdout-for-vs-code)
- [Debug output doesn't appear in debug console without "outputCapture": "std" #41600](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41600)

### Related

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Comment: Deno launch configuration template seems to have been (temporarily?) removed again, as you need to insert it manually now

Comment: This needs upvotes. This answer made me restart and F5 indeed works out of the box. After which I auto-generated the launch.json like ford04 suggested and just added outputCapture and the whole thing worked.

Answer (score 10):

to debug **current file**, you can use below configuration :)

`"outputCapture": "std"` allows deno to print to VS code console

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Deno",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "-A", "${fileBasename}"],
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

P.S. just added to Evandro Pomatti's answer

Comment: that's pretty handy

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace `port` with `attachSimplePort`

```
{
    "name": "Deno",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
    "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "-A", "${fileBasename}"],
    "outputCapture": "std",
    "attachSimplePort": 9229
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the official Deno extension, Then generate a configuration by opening the **Run and Debug** panel, selecting Create a **launch.json** file, and choosing the Deno option from the debugger options.