# Cannot run deno debugger on vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, deno

I am a reccent deno user. Been using node for a long time, switched to deno and am very happy with it. It's really good

However, I have an issue.
Whenever I try to debug a deno file, the vscode debugger starts running for like half a second and then stops, and nothing happens.
It doesnt freeze or anything, it just starts for a moment and stops.

I am using this as launch configuration

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Deno1",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run", "--inspect-brk", "-A", "${fileName}"],
            "port": 9229,

        }
    ]
}
```

I took it from  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853754/how-to-debug-deno-in-vscode)

I should add that I was able to debug this file already, but one day it just started showing this issue i just described without (to my knowledge) any change on my part.

I am trying to debug [this file](https://github.com/giluis/ccompilerts/blob/master/tests/grammar.test.ts)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Also, make sure you're using "test" as your first runtime argument, not "run" or you won't be able to set breakpoints or use the debugger

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you need to add a `"program"` field to `launch.json` and move the path of the file there, which is briefly mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64061274/12769288) from the post you linked to. But also you need to change `"port"` to `"attachSimplePort"`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "type": "node",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/grammar.test.ts", 
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "test",
                "--inspect-brk",
                "--allow-all"
            ],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229,
            "outputCapture": "std",
        }
    ]
}
```

To debug another part of the application just change the path in `program`, for example to an entrypoint file like `main.ts`. With `--inspect-brk` the debugger will first break at the first line of the program and then you can for example continue to a breakpoint with `F5` or the continue button in the debugger panel.

(Deno v1.14)