# Node.js morgan logger output does not appear on console

Tags: node.js, morgan

I'm handling a new project with node.js backend and my `morgan` logger works quite wired. At first I was unable to get any output from it using any of predefined morgan templates (`tiny`, `short`, e.c.t) nothing was propagated to output. I provided custom logging function to verify does the morgan is called at all on my stack:

```
app.use(morgan((tokens, req, res) => {
console.log('AAAAAAAAAAA');
return 'ABABABABABAA';
}, { stream: process.stdout }));
```

Sequence of `AAAAAAAAAAA` is indeed propagated to console output via `console.log` inside logging function (proof that morga in actually called on each request), but logging function does not provide it's `ABABABABABA` sequence at all.

As long as I'm able to imagine that predefined format may fail due to non-conventional names of `req`/`res` objects (which is by the way not a case), then returning plain text from logger function shall be obviously propagated to output straight through.

#### Edit

Setting morgan option to `{immediate: true}` also does not resolve issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: For me, on clean project setup it's working as well, so the question is rather is there any node/express gotchas thah may prevent it from working

Comment: It's strange that a `console.log` would work but returning the string (which would be written to `process.stdout` at some point) wouldn't. So I have no obvious ideas on what could be causing this.

Comment: I was thinking about some custom error handling that will stop response form propagation, but then `{immidiate: true}` would work correctly - its's not

Comment: It's also strange that the predefined templates don't work. Perhaps you're using more than one instance of `morgan` in your app? Not sure if that would break things, but who knows.

Comment: nope, `morgan` was not used in app (only manual logging). That's a reason why I wanted to plug `morgan` :)

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the problem was that I didn't call 'morgan' right after creating the app. When I changed its position, it solved the issue. I couldn't find any reference in 'morgan' page about this, but I found it in another answer here: [Express Morgan not writing logs to file or STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904450/express-morgan-not-writing-logs-to-file-or-stdout)

**Working solution:**

```
let app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))     <--- morgan right after app
app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use('/', routes)
```

**Not working code (previously):**

```
let app = express()
app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use('/', routes)
app.use(morgan('combined'))     <--- morgan
```

Comment: Unfortunately, In my case `morgan` is the first middlewere registered in app (just like in your "working" example). Anyway thank you for contributing, maybe this will help someone other

Comment: Ok. I tried your exact code in a small app, and it's printing both 'AAAAAAAAAAA' and 'ABABABABABAA'. Maybe it's something else, maybe you could show more details of your app code.

Comment: This solved my issue.

Why does the order matter and is that an issue on express' side?

Comment: The solution worked for me, Thanks!! but didn't understand the reason behind the specific ordering

Comment: I passed in 'tiny' instead of combined as I didn't need all of the extra stuff, just wanted the response code

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks!